# Triple double quotes in pycharm highlights as green and not grey

Tags: pycharm

I am using pycharm and it shows the entire block of code in triple double quotes in green and not in grey color (color for commented section).

But it perfect when I am using in sublime. How can I make it turn grey?

```
"""
It is a really long string
triple-quoted strings are used
to define multi-line strings
"""
```

Answer (score 1):

Preferences => Editor => Colors & Fonts => Python => `Docstring` Make this the same colour as your usual comment colour.

By default docstrings appear as a different colour as they aren't usual comments.

Comment: I made the following changes both on docstring and docstring tags and it still shows green after I click 'Apply'.

Comment: Ok. I've not added comments below the method but outside the method and it shows green within the method with an indent it shows grey. How can I make it grey everywhere , it doesn't matter if it is inside or outside the method.

Comment: I think it's `Language Defaults => Doc Comment`. Making them the same colour as comments should always make it the same colour. If not it should be something else under `Comments`

Comment: I did this also. But It's still green!